# Vuejs - не выходит передать переменную через props/v-bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Доброго времени суток. Никак не выходит передать в компонент переменную через props. Пример моего кода:

HTML:

```
<div id='app-container'>         
    <user-edit v-bind:current-user-id="editID"></user-edit>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var userEditComponent = {
    template: '<p>{{currentUserID}}</p>',
    props: ['currentUserID']
};

var vm = new Vue ({
    el: '#app-container',
    data: {
        editID: 123
    },
    components: {
        userEdit: userEditComponent
    },
});
```

Результат - эта переменная currentUserID в компоненте всегда undefined, хотя вроде бы как в других компонентах передача таким способом работает. Не могу никак понять что упустил. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка в имени, при передаче в пропсы  переменная должна записаться как `currentUserId`, а не как `currentUserID`.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/173148)

Comment: Почему не является ответом? Смысл в том, что автор передает переменную `current-user-id`, которая в пропсах должна записаться как `currentUserId`, а не как `currentUserID`.

Comment: Вероятно, эти пояснения стоит добавить прямо в ваш ответ. Так случайному посетителю (в чьей роли я был) проще будет разобраться.

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: И это правильный ответ. Спасибо за подсказку. Я лично очень хотел чтоб та D была большой, но видимо, что лучше не спорить с вуежс

Comment: Чисто теоретически этого можно достигнуть написав так: `current-user-i-d` :)